# boost::unique_lock desturctor error, status corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

I have a `IO_Operation` function which will initiate a io thread to do something asynchronously. But I only allow one IO thread running at a time, so I use a unique lock to do this.

here is my code:

```
    void MyClass::IO_Operation(...) {
      std::thread(&MyClass::IO_Worker, this, ...).detach();
    }


    void MyClass::IO_Worker(...) {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> io_thread_lock(this->iothread_mutex_, boost::defer_lock_t());
    bool own_lock = io_thread_lock.try_lock();
    if (!own_lock) return;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
```

the code will produce this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost unique_lock doesn't own the mutex: Operation not permitted
```

The error happened when exiting the function, in the `boost::unique_lock` destructor, I've looked at the source code for `boost::unique_lock` at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp

its destructor is

```
~unique_lock()
    {
      if (owns_lock())
      {
        m->unlock();
      }
    }


void unlock()
{
  if (m == 0)
  {
    boost::throw_exception(
        boost::lock_error(static_cast<int>(system::errc::operation_not_permitted), "boost unique_lock has no mutex"));
  }
  if (!owns_lock())
  {
    boost::throw_exception(
        boost::lock_error(static_cast<int>(system::errc::operation_not_permitted), "boost unique_lock doesn't own the mutex"));
  }
  m->unlock();
  is_locked = false;
}
```

it seems that the status this `unique_lock` was corrupted, the `owns_lock()` return true at the first place but return false then.....This unique_lock is a lock variable so it's impossible that other threads mutate the status of it.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere in the code. No idea where. By the way, `std` has it[s own `unique_lock` now, no need to use boost.

Comment: Can we get a reproducible [mcve]?